# Show an activity element over fragment

Tags: android

I have an Activity that shows a fragment.

First I load saved data from sharedPreference to dont show an empty fragment.

Then, the real time data for the fragment is requested with AsyncTask, and I show and hide a progress bar on onPreExecute() and onPostExecute() when Im requesting the data but the progressBar is shown behind fragment layout.

Is there a way to show it over the fragment layout and not behind the fragment?

Any help will be appreciated.

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pb_loading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Horario" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_schedule"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>    
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you share your layout xml

Comment: please always consider add related code in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make like this. Change your root layout to relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks. and with android:layout_centerInParent="true" in progressbar it is in the center of the screen

Answer (score 0):

If your Fragment's container and ProgressBar are in the same layout as siblings you can call bringToFront() on your ProgressBar.

Comment: ProgressBar is in Activity where the AsyncTask is executed